# how to get start and end date of external dragged and dropped event on fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar

I have a quick question about fullcalendars drag and drop functionality.

Here is my JS Code

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        right: 'title'
    },
    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
    drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

        // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
        var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
        console.log(originalEventObject.title);

        // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
        var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

        // assign it the date that was reported
        // console.log(originalEventObject.start);
        // console.log(originalEventObject.end);
        copiedEventObject.start = date;
        copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

        // render the event on the calendar
        // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
            // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
            $(this).remove();
        }

    }
});
```

I would like to create a new variable called **var dragged_event** that looks something like below with each dragged and dropped event.

```
var dragged_event = "Name: " + originalEventObject.title + ", Start: " + ??? + ", End: " + ???
```

So the output look like something similar

```
console.log(dragged_event);
//Name: Birthday Start: Mar 06 2014 End: Mar 08 2014
```

Currently I'm unable to determined how to get the Start and End date of the dragged event. Could anyone lend me a hand in solving this please?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like

```
drop: function (date, allDay) {

          console.clear();
          console.log("dropped");
          console.log(date.format());


          var defaultDuration = moment.duration($('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'defaultTimedEventDuration'));
          var end = date.clone().add(defaultDuration); // on drop we only have date given to us
          console.log('end is ' + end.format());

        // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
        var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

        // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
        var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);



        // assign it the date that was reported
        copiedEventObject.start = date;
        copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

        copiedEventObject.backgroundColor = $(this).css("background-color");
        copiedEventObject.borderColor = $(this).css("border-color");

        // render the event on the calendar
        // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
          // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
          $(this).remove();
        }

      }
```

Gives this result

[image]

OR follow this example.

- http://jsfiddle.net/dg9gp3e3/3/

Answer (score 1):

There is on overload for

> drop: function(date, allDay)

wich is

> drop: function(start, end, allDay)

The start and end dates are stored into the 'start' and 'end' variables.